# Python - Create objects with indexed names

Tags: python

I want to make a list of dictionaries that I can append an updated dictionary with a new name (indexed) each time I iterate through a certain code, in which dict is updated.

```
 dict = {'Key1': 'Value1'
         'Key2': 'Valeu2'
         }   

 list1 = [dict1, dict2, dictx, ....]
```

So basicly I define dict and then i run the loop the first time, now what i want to happen is that dict will be updated according to the code and then be appeneded to list1 by the name dict1, and by the 2nd iteration it will be dict2 and so on. Ofcourse each of the dictionaries will have it's own items.

Comment: I don't understand. Where do `dict1` and `dict2` and `dictx` come from? Why do you even have a bunch of variables with numbers at the end? Why didn't you store your dicts in a list to begin with?

Comment: dont name a dictionary dict its an inbuilt function

Comment: @Aran That's not my code, that's what I want to happen. I want the updated dictioanry (after each iteration) to be stored in the list with a new name so I'll have a list of all the dictioanries created through the iterations

Comment: But why does it have to be stored in the list *and* have a name? Why do you need the name?

Comment: @Aran Later I want to do stuff with all the created dictioanries, assuming the thing I want is even possible, is it? or are we just argueing over nothing

Comment: It is possible, but 99.999999% of the time it's a horrible idea. If you need to do stuff with the created dictionaries, you can access them through the list. You don't need to assign them to names.

Comment: @Aran If I don't change their names all the prevoius items in the list will be updated each time so they will all point to the same dictionary.

Comment: That has nothing at all to do with names. You simply need to create a new dictionary instead of updating the old one.

Comment: @Aran How do I do it without overriding the previous one?

Comment: Well, you know how to create a dictionary. (`my_dict = {...}`) You just need to do that inside of your loop. See also [Why get unexpected dict](//stackoverflow.com/q/52179509)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your dictionaries do exist somewhere - you can store their names as list of strings and later 'extract' them when required using eval()

```
mydict0 = {'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Valeu2'}
mydict1 = {'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Valeu2'}
mydict2 = {'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Valeu2'}
mydict3 = {'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Valeu2'}

mylist = ["mydict0", "mydict1", "mydict2", "mydict3"]

> eval(mylist[0])
> {'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Valeu2'}
```

Alternatively, if you create dictionaries dynamically, you could create dictionary of dictionaries:

```
dict_of_dicts = {}

for i in range(20):
    key = "mydict{}".format(i)
    value = {'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Valeu2'}   
    dict_of_dicts[key] = value

> dict_of_dicts

{'mydict0': {'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Valeu2'},
 'mydict1': {'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Valeu2'},
 'mydict2': {'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Valeu2'},
 ...

> dict_of_dicts["mydict0"]
> {'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Valeu2'}
```